# MQ MFT configuration and MFT resource monitor move to new server same OS

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

MQ Manager MQ 7.5 on Linux

Are the MQ MFT *resource monitor* (fteCreateMonitor) definitions contained in the MQ Queue Manager queue definitions (like fte.xxxx) ?

If so, can I simply use the command

> dmpmqcfg -m QMA -a > /mq/backups/QMA.mqsc

and restore the configuration on a queue manager with the same name and IP/Hostname (clone) and the resource monitors will be recreated without further effort?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use

1) fteListMonitors command to export task definition to a xml file.

2) Use that xml file with fteCreateMonitor command to recreate the resource monitor on another queue manager.

For example:
Export the resource task definition on machine 1.

```
fteListMonitors -ma SRC -mn QMON -ox c:\temp\qmon.xml
```

Take the `qmon.xml` file to machine 2 and run the following command

```
fteCreateMonitor -ix C:\temp\qmon.xml -ma SRC -mn QMON
```

Comment: Would I not be able to copy the queue manager's configuration from /var/mqm/qmgrs/QMA to the other server?  It seems when I did this, it copied all the content of a file SYSTEM!FTE!EVENTS!AGENT!NAME , that file contained all the xml related to the monitors.